# Xpath return wrong output than in XPath helper in browser

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using XPath helper in order to create my paths, however for the first time i seem to get a complete wrong output. I've created following path to get the articles links on the current day. just to test i've hardcoded the current date.

```
//b[contains(., '22/4 - 2015')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class='newsItem']
```

Instead of returning each newsItem, which it does in XPath Helper, it returns the whole page? how come is that. here is my code

```
function scrape() {
    $hltv = file_get_html("http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=96");
    foreach($hltv->find("//b[contains(., '22/4 - 2015')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class='newsItem']") as $hltv_element) {
        echo $hltv_element;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked the `$hltv` value? Try to cut a piece of html and insert it manually into `$htlv` and perform xpath on it.

Comment: it seem to work if just do like: //div[@class='newsItem']. Why does it not function with all the following-siblings parent etc. ? is simple html dom using an old version of XPath or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you would like to get as the result, but here is a snippet of relevant HTML to hopefully make that clearer:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px;">
                <b>22/4 - 2015</b>
            </div>
            <div class="newsItem">
                <a href="/news/14794-video-pyth-vs-dignitas" id="newsitem14794" title="Video: pyth vs. dignitas">
                    <span style="float:left;">
                        <img style="vertical-align: 1px;" src="http://static.hltv.org//images/mod_csgo.png" title="Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"/>
                        <img src="http://static.hltv.org//images/flag/se.gif" alt="" />&nbsp;</span> <span style="float:left;cursor: hand;width:350px;color:#000000"/>
                        <b>Video: pyth vs. dignitas</b>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <span style="float: right;">(22)</span>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div class="newsItem"><a href="/news/14795-video-keev-vs-myxmg" id="newsitem14795" title="Video: keev vs. myXMG">
                <span style="float:left;">
                    <img style="vertical-align: 1px;" src="http://static.hltv.org//images/mod_csgo.png" title="Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"/>
```

As you can see, there is a `<b>22/4 - 2015</b>` that is selected. But its parent, the first `div` in the snippet, has more than one following `div` siblings where `@class="newsItem"`. Perhaps you meant to have

```
//b[contains(., '22/4 - 2015')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class='newsItem'][1]
```

> is simple html dom using an old version of XPath or?

In my opinion, all libraries that include "simple" in their name (SimpleXML, Simple HTML DOM) are not so simple really, and often cause problems. All libraries use XPath 1.0, so that's not the problem. You are better off using DOMDocument and [`DomXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

**EDIT**

> just to be clear: I want to get the titles of the news on the current date

Then use

```
//b[contains(., '22/4 - 2015')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class='newsItem'][1]/a/@title
```

Comment: just to be clear: I want to get the titles of the news on the current date

Comment: @PeterPik I've edited my answer. Is the title you are looking for the attribute `title`, inside the `a` element?

Comment: title and the link :) i'm going to loop through the newsItem